# How to configure Angular secondary route?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to configure secondary routes within a component where the content of the routes are displayed in tabs

In `app.component.html`

`<a class="list" [routerLink]="[{outlets:{primary:'variationMargin', futuresMargin:'futuresMargin'}}]" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">Projected VM</a>`

In `variation-margin.routing.module.ts`
I am trying to configure secondary routes within a component where the content of the routes are displayed in tabs

In `app.component.html`

`<a class="list" [routerLink]="[{outlets:{primary:'variationMargin', futuresMargin:'futuresMargin'}}]" routerLinkActive="router-link-active">Projected VM</a>`

In `variation-margin.routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: 'variationMargin',
    component: VariationMarginComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
}, {
    path: 'futuresMargin,
    component: FuturesMarginComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    outlet: 'futuresMargin'
}];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class VariationMarginRoutingModule { }
```

Within the template for `VariationMarginComponent` I have tabs

```
tab1 -> the primary route i.e. the VariationMarginComponent
tab2 -> <router-outlet name='futuresMargin'></router-outlet>
```

In `futures-margin.routing.module.ts`. I am not using this component as a standalone route so not sure if this matters.

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: AppSettings.FuturesMarginRoute,
    component: FuturesMarginComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    outlet: 'futuresMargin'
}];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FuturesMarginRoutingModule { }
```

However nothing is showing up for `futuresMargin` in `tab2`. I see just he the blank tab.

How should I configure the route for it to show up in the `tab2`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution is far simpler and the router link needs to be as if it does not even know about the secondary route

```
<a class="list" routerLink='variationMargin routerLinkActive="router-link-active">Projected VM</a>
```